# sending a signal via kill and pid=0

Tags: kill, signals

From kill's `man`:

> If pid is 0, sig shall be sent to all processes (excluding an
>   unspecified set of system processes) whose process group ID is equal
>   to the process group ID of the sender, and for which the process has
>   permission to send a signal

What does `for which the process has permission to send a signal` exactly mean? 
How can I check which processes will receive a signal?

For example, `kill -9 0` kills every process that was started in the current **tty** and the **tty** itself. Or is there something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does `for which the process has permission to send a signal` exactly mean?

It's answered right there in the manpage:

> For  a  process  to  have  permission  to send a signal it must either be privileged, or the real or  effective  user  ID  of  the  sending process  must  equal  the  real or saved set-user-ID of the target process. In the case of **SIGCONT** it suffices when the sending and receiving processes belong to the same session.

> How can I check which processes will receive a signal?

You could walk the process list and try to kill each one with signal 0 (the dry run signal). That will tell you whether you would have had permission to send a real signal.

Comment: In translation: if you don't have elevated permissions, then you have permission if the process belongs to you.

Comment: @richard pretty much